# I can't understand these two questions

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, scheduling, job-scheduling, context-switch

Consider a system with 1 CPU, running 10 100% CPU-bound jobs. Assume
the following times:

- Total CPU time needed by each job: 10s
- Job scheduling: 100ms
- CPU scheduling: 5ms
- Context switch: 5ms

A. If jobs are executed batch (no multitasking), how long does it take…

- For all jobs to complete?
- For the first job to complete?
- For the average job to complete?

Consider a system with 1 CPU, running 10 100% CPU-bound jobs. Assume
the following times:

- Total CPU time needed by each job: 10s
- Maximum CPU burst before context switch: 100ms
- CPU scheduling: 5ms
- Context switch: 5ms

B. If jobs are executed interactively (multitasking, no job scheduling), how
long does it take…

- For all jobs to complete?
- For the first job to complete?
- For the average job to complete?
- What is the operating-system overhead?

I know that in multitasking context switch is not considered (or is it?) and I know what job scheduling and CPU scheduling is but I still can't wrap my head around this numerical. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not (yet) a programming question.